# Subclassing .NET List objects, using .Distinct and .ToList

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I am trying to implement a StringList class in VB.NET by subclassing List(Of String). Most List methods work unchanged for the StringList class, but when the method involves an iterator.ToList() the result is a generic list that cannot be downcasted back to the class.

Consider the code:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a0 As New List(Of String) From {"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Banana"}
        Dim b0 As New StringList From {"Asparagus", "Broccoli", "Cucumber", "Broccoli"}

        Dim a1 As List(Of String) = a0.Distinct.ToList  ' list of 3 strings
        Dim b1 As StringList = b0.Distinct.ToList   ' runtime exception invalid cast from List(Of String) to StringList
    End Sub
End Module

Class StringList
    Inherits List(Of String)

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Strings.Join(Me.ToArray, ", ")
    End Function
End Class
```

The `b1` assignment will fail because `.Distinct` returns an iterator and `.ToList` returns a `List(Of String)` which cannot be cast to a `StringList`.

What is the right way to implement either `Distinct()` or `ToList()` so that I can use `StringList` instead of generic lists?

Comment: If `StringList` is as simple as you show, I'd seriously question whether it needs to exist at all. Is it really so important that `ToString` behaves differently? An extension method on `List(Of String)` that calls `String.Join()` could easily be added to your project, just with a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damien_The_Unbeliever and jmcilhinney have pointed to solutions that both work, but in different ways. Which you use depends on your preferences and future plans for the `StringList` class, but neither is totally clean, in the sense of the code being agnostic as to whether you are using `List(Of String)` or `StringList`.

Damien_The_Unbeliever's solution dispenses with the `StringList` class, relegating it to an `Imports`, and extends `List(Of String)`:

```
Imports StringList = System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a0 As New List(Of String) From {"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Banana"}
        Dim b0 As New StringList From {"Asparagus", "Broccoli", "Cucumber", "Broccoli"}

        Dim a1 As List(Of String) = a0.Distinct.ToList  ' list of 3 strings
        Dim b1 As StringList = b0.Distinct.ToList   ' likewise
        Console.WriteLine(b1.ToString2())    ' works, but you can't override ToString()
    End Sub

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ToString2(ByVal s As StringList) As String
        Return Strings.Join(s.ToArray, ", ")
    End Function
End Module
```

jmcilhinney's solution retains `StringList` as a true class, and extends `IEnumerable(Of String)` with a method that yields a `StringList` object:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a0 As New List(Of String) From {"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Banana"}
        Dim b0 As New StringList From {"Asparagus", "Broccoli", "Cucumber", "Broccoli"}

        Dim a1 As List(Of String) = a0.Distinct.ToList  ' list of 3 strings
        Dim b1 As StringList = b0.Distinct.ToStringList   ' works, but you can't use ToList()
        Console.WriteLine(b1.ToString())
    End Sub

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ToStringList(ByVal sl As IEnumerable(Of String)) As StringList
        Dim ret As New StringList From {}
        For Each i As String In sl
            ret.Add(i)
        Next
        Return ret
    End Function
End Module

Class StringList
    Inherits List(Of String)

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Strings.Join(Me.ToArray, ", ")
    End Function
End Class
```

Take your pick, and thanks to both responders.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own `ToStringList` method.  `ToList` is an extension method so you should write `ToStringList` as an extension method too, extending `IEnumerable(Of String)`.